# Probability that none has to wait for change

Tags: probability

Suppose $2n$ customers stand in line at a box office, $n$ with $5$-dollar bills and
$n$ with $10$-dollar bills. Suppose each ticket costs $5$ dollars, and the box office
has no money initially. What is the probability that none of the customers has
to wait for change?

Comment: This is directly related to [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

Comment: Look at it in terms of left and right parentheses

Comment: Catalan numbers argument doesn't work e.g. for $n=2$ you cannot have a string like $(0,5,10)$ otherwise you cannot return $5$-dollars in the next turn.

Comment: @беркай What exactly does $(0,5,10)$ represent? We just need that the $k$th 10-dollar person comes after the $k$th 5-dollar person (for all $k$) which is directly related to Catalan numbers.

Comment: @blf OK! Take $n=1$. If first 10-dollar person comes after first 5-dollar person then it fails because the box office now has 10 dollars (consisting of one 10 dollars and zero 5 dollars) and it cannot return 5 dollars in the next round if anyone pays 10 dollars. Do I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @беркай Yes, you are correct! The Catalan numbers work because they count only the cases where the $k$th 10-dollar person comes after the $k$th 5-dollar person; the case you just described would not be counted. For $n=1$, we have $C_1 = \binom{2}{1}-\binom{2}{2}=2-1=1$, which counts only the case that the 5-dollar person comes first.

Comment: @blf That's good! I also want to understand the case $n=2$ which leads to $C_2=2$. Now, we should have in the first place 5-dollar person, second 5-dollar person, third and forth 10 dollar-persons. However, if we pick 5-dollar and 10-dollar persons identical then we have just 1 way to arrange them (This is not the case, indeed). Otherwise, assuming that they are different then we have 4 ways (5-dollar and 10 dollar-persons can change place among themselves). Most probably, you don't count the one who is the first or the last? What's the idea?

Comment: @беркай You've forgotten the case where the 5-dollar people are in positions 1 and 3. The Catalan numbers consider all 5-dollar people the same, and all 10-dollar people the same. In the context of OP's question, we would just need to multiply the Catalan number by $(n!)^2$ if all people are distinguishable.

Comment: @blf: As the question asks for probability, it doesn't matter whether we consider the people distinguishable or not (assuming the sample spaces have the same distribution): it will be $1/(n+1)$ in either case.

Comment: @blf Again 5-dollar people cannot be in the positions 1 and 3. That's exactly why I first objected the use of Catalan numbers in this context. If you place 5-dollar people to 1 and 3.place, it means that one of the 10-dollar persons is on the 2.place which doesn't guarantee that he will return 5-dollars in the next round so this case cannot be considered. This is the way that I understood this problem, otherwise, your argument works!

Comment: @беркай Why doesn't it work? The 1st person gives 5 dollars. Then the 2nd person gives 10 dollars and receives a 5-dollar bill. Then the 3rd person gives 5 dollars. Then the 4th person gives 10 dollars and receives a 5-dollar bill.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yes you are correct; in the context of the problem it doesn't matter. I just wanted to clarify it for the other commenter who was not sure if they were distinguishable or not.

Comment: @blf Of course, it is a possiblity but if you place the first two places like this, you assume that the box office will gain 5 dollars in the third round. As far as I understand, the officer should be ready in each round to return money back. What if he receives 10 dollars in the third round in this case?

Comment: @беркай We calculate the probability by considering all orderings of the $2n$ people, so any given ordering is "good" or "bad," and we don't do casework on partial orderings (like what you are doing by looking only at the first 2 people instead of all 4).